# how to plot two functions as a same function with same x axis?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a code that produces standing waves. I am getting the standing waves but the forward wave and backward wave that I have created are two different functions that's why different colors are appearing. now I want to write the forward and backward waves in a single function?

the code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=linspace(0,4*np.pi,10001)
y=np.sin(x)
yn=(-y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,-y)
```

**how to modify it and plot it as a single function.**

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO :)

A function that contains two functions means `f(x)=>(y, -y)`, and this is illegal according to plot function documentation and would cause `x and y must have same first dimension` error and moreover it is against the theoretical definition of the `function` itself! But if you are into unifying the graph colors why don't you set it manually?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=linspace(0,4*np.pi,10001)
y=np.sin(x)
yn=(-y)
plt.plot(x,y, color='red')
plt.plot(x,-y, color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess on of the efficient ways to achieve it

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,10001)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,'b-', x, -y, 'b-')
```

Hopefully, it helps